# Excel VBA Macro open sheets and ignore if not found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro code to open several excel sheets one after the other (I only show 3 here):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("F19").Value, UpdateLinks:=0
    ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    Windows("Data Quality Checks - ITS v2.8.xlsm").Activate

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("F21").Value, UpdateLinks:=0
    ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    Windows("Data Quality Checks - ITS v2.8.xlsm").Activate

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("F23").Value, UpdateLinks:=0
    ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    Windows("Data Quality Checks - ITS v2.8.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

The 'Range' shows the cell with the specific file path. 
Currently, if the macro does not find one of the files, it produces an error and the process is forced to stop. Is it possible to include an additional line code that if the file is not found in the specified path, then the process continues and does not stop (no debugging)?

Comment: add at the top
On error resume next

Comment: @patel never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling! That might be the worst idea you can have. [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Use `DIR` to check if the file exists before trying to open it...

Comment: Also instead of activating the `Windows("Data Quality Checks - ITS v2.8.xlsm")` everytime. Simply assign the workbook to a *workbook* object and then use `wb.Range("F19").Value` to refer to the cell which has the file name and path

Answer (score 0):

This may helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim PathName As String, MissingFiles As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 19 To LastRow Step 2 '<- Start from 19 like the example and stop lastrow column A sheet 1. Loop every two.

                PathName = .Range("A" & i).Value

                If Len(Dir(PathName)) = 0 Then '<- Make sure you add the extension of the file.
                    If MissingFiles = "" Then
                        MissingFiles = PathName
                    Else
                        MissingFiles = MissingFiles & vbNewLine & PathName
                    End If
                Else
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName, UpdateLinks:=0
                    ActiveWindow.Visible = True
'                    Windows("Data Quality Checks - ITS v2.8.xlsm").Activate
                End If

            Next i

            MsgBox "Missing Files are: " & vbNewLine & MissingFiles

    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet Structure:**

[image]

**Message Box :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. @Error1004, I tested your suggestion and whilst a debugging error is not displayed, the process stops if the file is not fund, presumably due to the "Exit Sub" part. How can I indicate that     If Len(Dir(.Range("A1").Value)) = 0 Then (continue to next IF command checking whether the 2nd file exists)?